# Spotify Playlist mini project

Tags: java

These are my instructions:
Focus: Create a class SpotifyPlaylist that can contain as many as 1000 songs. The Spotify Playlist should contain an array made up of Song objects.
Song Class: The song class will be used to create songs.  Each song has a title, artist, album, length, genre, and number of times it was played.  Be sure to include any necessary methods.
SpotifyPlayist Class: Should be able to
-Add a song
-Print out all songs
-Print out all songs that are on a given album
-Print out all songs of a given genre
-Print a list of all songs by a given artist
-Print out top 10 most popular songs.
-Play a song (Add 1 to number of times played, not actually play music)
-Remove a song given the title.
Be sure to include any necessary methods that may help.For example, it might be good to write a method that checks if a Song is in the playlist.Tester: Creates a SpotifyPlaylistobject and showcases all its features.

I dont have much: I only have the song class. I was a bit stuck on how to start the arrays for my playlist class. Anything helps, TY!

```
public class Song
{
   // Fields
   private String title;
   private String artist;
   private String album;
   private double lengthOfSong; // in seconds 
   private String genre;
   private int numOfTimesPlayed;

    // Constructors
    /**
     * Empty Constructor
     */
    public Song() {
    }

    /**
     * Overloaded Constructor for objects of class
     */
    public Song(String title, String artist, String album, double lengthOfSong, String genre, int numOfTimesPlayed) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.lengthOfSong = lengthOfSong;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.numOfTimesPlayed = numOfTimesPlayed;
    }

    // Getters
    ...        

    // Setters
    ...        

    // Methods

    /**
     * toString of the info of the class Song
     */
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Song: ";
        s = s + "Title: " +  getTitle() + " ";
        s = s + "Artist: " + getArtist() + " ";
        s = s + "Name of album: " + getAlbum() + " ";
        s = s + "Length of song: " + getLengthOfSong() + " ";
        s = s + "Genre of song: " + getGenre() + " ";
        s = s + "Number of time played: " + getNumOfTimesPlayed() + " ";
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * A method that plays a song again
     */
    public void playAgain() {
        numOfTimesPlayed = numOfTimesPlayed + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your  instance variables, you can just add any type of List to hold the list of all your songs (and later create more if you find yourself needing them).

A good start is an ArrayList.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
If you skim through the doc, you can see that you can add, remove, check, etc. using an array list. Keep in mind some of the actions run slow.
In your playlist class, you would hold just this in the instance variables

```
private ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then just initialize songs and add them to the ArrayList.

This website tells you some runtimes of different data structures that you might find helpful. For instance, some have very fast insertion or deletion. https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Creating a doc sheet with all the methods that you intend to use can be helpful for you to see exactly what you would need to track. Personally, I would just start with an ArrayList and then after you get the main parts to work, try to work for more efficient code.

Comment: TYSM! I am new to java and I appreciate the help.